Grid is going out of column
This question is regarding the display: grid which is taking up the space outside the container and how to fix this issue. I have created a product grid which looks like

I want to acheive the design like this

ol.products.list.items.product-items {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
   gap: 0px;
   height: 100%;
   max-width: 1440px;
}
li.item.product.product-item:nth-child(1) {
 
   background-color: #857E57; 
   grid-row-start: 1;
   grid-column-start: 1;
 
   grid-row-end: 2;
   grid-column-end: 2;
}
li.item.product.product-item:nth-child(2) {
 
   background-color: #95C985; 
   grid-row-start: 1;
   grid-column-start: 2;
 
   grid-row-end: 2;
   grid-column-end: 3;
}
li.item.product.product-item:nth-child(3) {
 
   background-color: #B5E85F; 
   grid-row-start: 1;
   grid-column-start: 3;
 
   grid-row-end: 3;
   grid-column-end: 5;
}
li.item.product.product-item:nth-child(4) {
 
   background-color: #A55867; 
   grid-row-start: 2;
   grid-column-start: 2;
 
   grid-row-end: 3;
   grid-column-end: 3;
}
li.item.product.product-item:nth-child(5) {
 
   background-color: #87F79D; 
   grid-row-start: 2;
   grid-column-start: 1;
 
   grid-row-end: 3;
   grid-column-end: 2;
}
li.item.product.product-item:nth-child(6) {
 
   background-color: #575FD7; 
   grid-row-start: 3;
   grid-column-start: 1;
 
   grid-row-end: 5;
   grid-column-end: 3;
}
li.item.product.product-item:nth-child(7) {
 
   background-color: #5C6C9D; 
   grid-row-start: 3;
   grid-column-start: 3;
 
   grid-row-end: 4;
   grid-column-end: 4;
}
li.item.product.product-item:nth-child(8) {
 
   background-color: #5F58AC; 
   grid-row-start: 3;
   grid-column-start: 4;
 
   grid-row-end: 4;
   grid-column-end: 5;
}
li.item.product.product-item:nth-child(9) {
 
   background-color: #B7E768; 
   grid-row-start: 4;
   grid-column-start: 3;
 
   grid-row-end: 5;
   grid-column-end: 4;
}
li.item.product.product-item:nth-child(10) {
 
   background-color: #75F656; 
   grid-row-start: 4;
   grid-column-start: 4;
 
   grid-row-end: 5;
   grid-column-end: 5;
}```

Explanation of the code I have used CSS grids. ol tag is parent li is child I have used nth child since it's going to be static.  The above code is written with nth child as the product list page has pagination for 10 products per page.  Could someone suggest a way to make it **fit inside the container**? I have checked the   for the old and it's parent tags. it all looks good fitting inside the container   I'm expecting the output like the above image
The design is achievable but going outside the container.


Please provide the code in the form of a [repro] inkl the necessary HTML markup. I can not reproduce the issue with CSS alone.

You are using an ordered list. Where do you want those numbers to appear?

I don't want the numbers to appear I want the li tags all to be enclosed inside the container @AHaworth
